# Spring JPA findBy accent

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I am developing a spring-data-jpa application. 
I 've ridden the repository with `findBy` but does not work when I look content with an accent. Does anyone know why? 
I am using the following:

```
Page<Dades> findByNomcomercialIgnoreCaseContaining (@Param ("nomcom") String nomcom, Pageable pageable);
```

The database is Oracle.

Thanks for your interest.

Comment: I don't think you need the param annotation if you are trying to create the query from method name if you want to use param annotation then you will need to have the @query on top of the method. Also it will be nice to see the error logs and the entity.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `ignoreCase` does not deal with accents. It only compares both String after uppercasing them. See the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) for more informations.

I don't know any simple solution to ignore accents with Spring Jpa. You coud either :

1. Remove this parameter in your query, and filter the result in Java afterward (comparing Strings after doing `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.stripAccents`).
2. Use Spring Jpa Specifications. Again, it provides only functionslike `upper`, `like`, ... so you have to write your own, depending on what database you are using.

Answer (score -1):

@Param is not required. if you have any query i.e if you are using @Query then we need use @param to pass the specific value releated to query.Below you can check how to use @Query and @Param

```
 @Query("SELECT t.title FROM Todo t where t.id = :id") 
 String findTitleById(@Param("id") Long id);
```

if you are not added these annotation use in your repository layer

```
@Transactional
@Repository
```

Check another thing i.e

```
    @Transactional
    @Repository
    public interface IXyzRepository extends CrudRepository<ABC,Integer>{
    //some methods you have
    }
```

whether the primary id of ***class ABC*** is of type Integer